# Do you need time.deltatime in Rigidbody.addforce?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was recently working on a project and wondered this. Since addforce is instant, do you still need time.deltatime? My Forcemode2D is impulse, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the API [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html), you can see that `ForceMode.Impulse` is typically used as a single function call to provide an impulsive force immediately.

In general, you don't want to use `Time.DeltaTime` with any physics as multiplying force Time.deltaTime will actually result in dividing your force 50 times (there are 50 physics cycles per second, Time.deltaTime is 1/50).

If you're currently using `Time.DeltaTime` with your impulse call, removing it will probably result in a much stronger force being applied to your physics object.